# Apache rewrite_rule for angularjs

Tags: apache2.4

I have this rule in Angularjs app. It work perfectly. But I want to understand one rule which I don't know what it does `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] #???`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -!f 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] #NC none-case-sensitive, L stop when match
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

Please help me on this rule `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]` I know about the `[NC,L]` flags but I don't get `^.*$ -` especially the empty dash at the end of rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is:

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

Your rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

- `^.*$` is a perl compatible regular expression where

  - `^` is the start of string
  - `.` is any character except newline
  - `*` means 0 or more times
  - `$` is the end of string.
- The substiution is `-` which means: "no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag needs to be applied without changing the path."
- The flags are `NC` and `L`, which means:

  - `NC`:      Makes the pattern comparison case-insensitive.
  - `L`:   Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules. Especially note caveats for per-directory and .htaccess context (see also the END flag).

So this rule matches anything, makes no substitution, and stops the rewriting process immediately.

Comment: Thank you for response. Then, Can I say that the last rule `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L] ` never get match as this rule `^.*$ ` matches anything?

Comment: Yes, the pattern `^.*$` in combination with the flag `L`, make all subsequent rules not applied.